# Why does my code give an error of a Null Check Operator used on a null value

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies

Here is the code

I wanted to register a user and I used a FormKey and I got the error Null
check operator use don a null value

here is what the run terminal shows

E/flutter (30851): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] Unhandled Exception: Null check operator used on a null value
E/flutter (30851): #0      _RegisterScreenState.signUp (package:em_home/screens/signing/register_screen.dart:58:29)

```
class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const RegisterScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterScreenState createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  showSnackBar(String content, BuildContext context) {
    ScaffoldMessenger.of(context)
        .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(content)));
  }

  bool _isLoading = false;
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String email = "";
  String password = "";
  String fullName = "";
  String dob = "";
  String gender = "";
  AuthMethods authMethods = AuthMethods();
  Uint8List? image;

  pickImage(ImageSource source) async {
    final ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();

    XFile? _file = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: source);

    if (_file != null) {
      return await _file.readAsBytes();
    }
    print("No Image selected");
  }

  void selectImage() async {
    Uint8List im = await pickImage(ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      image = im;
    });
  }


  signUp() async {
    if (formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = true;
      });
      await authMethods.registerUser(email: email, password: password, name: fullName, gender: gender, dateOfBirth: dob,)
      .then((value) async {
        if (value == true) {
          await HelperFunctions.saveUserLoggedInStatus(true);
          await HelperFunctions.saveUserEmailSF(email);
          await HelperFunctions.saveUserNameSF(fullName);

          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, SlideLeftRoute(widget: const LoginScreen()));
        } else {
          showSnackBar(value, context);
          setState(() {
            _isLoading = false;
          });
        }
      });
    }
    return null;
  }

  void navigatetoSignIn() {
    Navigator.of(context)
        .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const LoginScreen()));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          color: backgroundColor,
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15),
          width: double.infinity,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Container(
                alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                child: IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacement(
                        context, SlideLeftRoute(widget: const LoginScreen()));
                  },
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.arrow_back,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              Image.asset(
                'assets/logos.png',
              ),
              const Text(
                "Create your account",
                style: TextStyle(color: textColor, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Stack(
                children: [
                  // to check if Image is not equal to null
                  image != null
                      ? CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 64,
                    backgroundImage: MemoryImage(image!),
                  )
                      : const CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 64,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage(
                      "assets/default_profile.jpg",
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    child: IconButton(
                      onPressed: selectImage,
                      icon: const Icon(Icons.add_a_photo),
                    ),
                    left: 80,
                    bottom: -10,
                  )
                ],
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                    labelText: "Email",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.email,
                    )),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    email = val;
                  });
                },

                // check tha validation
                validator: (val) {
                  return RegExp(
                      r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                      .hasMatch(val!)
                      ? null
                      : "Please enter a valid email";
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                obscureText: true,
                decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                    labelText: "Password",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.lock,
                      color: backgroundColor,
                    )),
                validator: (val) {
                  if (val!.length < 6) {
                    return "Password must be at least 6 characters";
                  } else {
                    return null;
                  }
                },
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    password = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                    labelText: "Full Name",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.person,
                    )),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    fullName = val;
                  });
                },
                validator: (val) {
                  if (val!.isNotEmpty) {
                    return null;
                  } else {
                    return "Name cannot be empty";
                  }
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                    labelText: "Date Of Birth DD/MM/YYYY",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.lock,
                    )),
                validator: (val) {},
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    dob = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              TextFormField(
                decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                    labelText: "Gender",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(
                      Icons.lock,
                    )),
                validator: (val) {},
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    gender = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 20,
              ),
              InkWell(
                onTap: signUp,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12),
                  decoration: const ShapeDecoration(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
                    ),
                    color: buttonColor,
                  ),
                  child: _isLoading
                      ? const Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                            color: iconButtonColor,
                          ),
                        )
                      : const Text(
                          "Sign up",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: buttonTextColor,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                ),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 50,
              ),
              Container(
                color: backgroundColor,
                child: const Text("- or sign in using -"),
              ),
              const SizedBox(
                height: 25,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: [
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, CustomRoute(widget: const Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Coming Soon"),))));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 45,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Image.asset('assets/google.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(
                    width: 30,
                  ),
                  GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      Navigator.push(context, CustomRoute(widget: const Scaffold(body: Center(child: Text("Coming Soon"),))));
                    },
                    child: Container(
                      width: 50,
                      height: 45,
                      color: Colors.white,
                      child: Image.asset('assets/facebook.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

please what do I do here is the snippet to the code

Comment: Exactly which line you are getting this error? Where does the form key used?

Comment: i got the error at the ``` if (formKey.currentState!.validate())```

Comment: Where does the form key used?

Comment: yes the place it is used

Comment: Where it is used? share the complete code snippet

Comment: it is used at the sign in button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your UI with the FormFields inside a Form widget and pass the GlobalKey to it.

Quick guide from Flutter docs: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation

Comment: Th ak you so much Ozan it worked